# Jenkins has no installation candidate : error while trying to install jenkins on ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, sudo, apt-get, dpkg

so im trying to install the jenkins on my ubuntu and ofc i made sure to update the system by running : apt update

**then i tried to run the following commands from jenkins website to install jenkins :**

"

```
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo tee \

/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null

echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \

https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

**then i got an error message that says :**

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Package jenkins is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or

is only available from another source

E: Package jenkins has no installation candidate
```

i barely understood, is that trying to recognize the repo which the files are downloading from?

**i saw a youtube video of someone who had the same problem and he use the following commands:**

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/... | sudo apt-get key add

'sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkind.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

**but it still doesnt work for me
can you help me please get jenkins installed ?**

Comment: How do I get to the **universe** Repository  https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository .........         jenkins https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jenkins&searchon=names

Answer (score 8):

You can add `[trusted=yes]` in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list` file.

Initially `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list` will have,

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/
```

Update it as,

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/
```

After that run the [installation instructions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/).

Eg: for [Debian releases](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontconfig openjdk-11-jre
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works at the moment for Ubuntu 22.10, Thanks @deshan

Answer (score 4):

I too had this problem and the issue was because I was using Zsh and not Bash. Once I switched to Bash (by typing "bash") the commands on the Jenkins website to install on Linux (Ubuntu for me) actually worked.

Comment: Thanks.....I had the same issue ....I changed to bash and it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

```
Just run this code step by step it will 

sudo apt update

sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre

java -version
 
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \
  /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins

sudo systemctl start jenkins.service

sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Although his answer doesn't support references, but, it's working!!
Thanks, man

Answer (score 2):

**Follow below commands to install the Jenkins in the ubuntu 18:04**

**command1 :**

curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo tee \

/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null

**command2 :**

echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \

https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

**command3:**

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins

sudo systemctl status jenkins

Access the URL http://hostname:8080

**use the below command to get the password**

more /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

Comment: /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null      ,,,

this gives me an error " permission denied"      ,,,,

i tried to do sudo at the start and got another error "command not found",,,

Comment: Hey These steps worked. Although it is already written in official docs. I forget to run apt-get update command and that is why same error as OP was coming.

Answer (score 2):

switch to root user first.
Command: sudo su -

Then you can run the commands you ran earlier to install Jenkins. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

1. install ca-certificates.

   `sudo apt install ca-certificates`
2. then install Jenkins from the official documentation

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

Comment: `E: Package jenkins has no installation candidate` is not an issue related to ca-certificates.

Answer (score 0):

first command
1.

```
 curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \
    /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null
```

Then add a Jenkins apt repository entry:
second command:-

```
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
    https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null
```

run these it worked for me

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install fontconfig openjdk-11-jre
  sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

First Install ca-certificate
1: sudo apt install ca-certificates
2: then install Jenkins from the official documentation
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#debianubuntu

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235544/3966456

Answer (score 0):

✅`E: Package jenkins has no installation candidate` **100% SOLVED**

As from June 2022 & later, Jenkins installation process was updated with newer & safer keys, hence the error `E: Package 'jenkins' has no installation candidate`

So to resolve this and gracefully install jenkins, the CICD automation server, follow these 3 simple steps:

**1. Update your local packages repository as sudo then add new keys (2023 Update) to the system.**

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \ /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null`

**2. Then add a Jenkins apt repository entry:**

`$ echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \ https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ | sudo tee \ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null`

**3. Update your local package index, install the JDK-17-JRE (2023 or newer) then finally install Jenkins:**

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install fontconfig openjdk-17-jre`

`$ sudo apt-get install jenkins`

To keep track of the ever-evolving DevSecOps world, kindly refer to the [Official Jenkins installation guide.](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/)

- Let us know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, I have faced that issue (E: Package 'jenkins' has no installation candidate) on Ubuntu 20.

It is working now

● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-02-10 05:47:08 UTC; 16s ago
Main PID: 2289311 (java)
Tasks: 50 (limit: 4686)

Just run the below commands:-

sudo apt dist-upgrade

wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'

sudo apt update

sudo apt install jenkins

systemctl status jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
```